# Is there a way to filter out multiple values at once using dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I know you can filter for values you want to keep using %in% but what if I wanted to remove a few values at once and keep the rest?

For example, I have a bunch of rows with transects numbers I want to keep but I want to remove all rows with transects 137, 22, and 141.

Comment: Try with something like `!x %in% values_to_drop`, e..g `!transects %in% c(137, 22, 141)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with iris data, removing some values of Sepal.Length:

```
library(tidyverse)
remove_values = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7)
iris %>% 
  filter(!(Sepal.Length %in% remove_values))
```

Comment: I understand you may have included the internal parentheses after `!` for clarity, but worth noting that they aren't strictly necessary.